# How to Split/Explode a string into a numbered lists in PHP?

Tags: php, explode, implode, preg-split

I am trying to split this string into numbered lists..

str options is "Hello,Howdy,Hola".

I need the output to be

1. Hello
2. Howdy
3. Hola

This is my code

```
$newstr = 'My values are' . explode(",", $str["options"]) . '<br/>';
```

However, This causes to only print the word Array. Please help me on this :((

Comment: You can not output an array with echo, or use it in a string concatenation context. Either write a _loop_ to go through the individual array elements, and append them to your string one by one, or use `implode` to transform your array into a string again, with whatever needs to be appended _between_ the individual elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) `explode()` with comma to make string as an array.

b) Iterate over it and concatenate number and text.

c) Save all these concatenated values to one string.

d) `echo` this string at end.

```
<?php
$str["options"] = "Hello,Howdy,Hola";
$data = explode(",", $str["options"]);

$newstr = 'My values are'. PHP_EOL;
foreach($data as $key => $value){
    $number = $key+1;
    $newstr .= "$number.". $value . PHP_EOL;
}
echo $newstr;
```

https://3v4l.org/lCYMk

Note:- you can use `<br>` instead of `PHP_EOL` as well.

Comment: Works like gem! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it will print this out in an html list tag

```
   <ol>

   <?php 

   $option = '';

   $newstr =  explode(",", $str["options"]) ;

   foreach($newstr as $option) {

   $option = trim($option); ?>

   <li><?php echo $option; ?></li>

  <?php } ?>

  </ol>
```

Comment: I tried this too. However it is only printing out number 1. The rest are empty.. :(

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to [explode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) your `array`. That will create an indexed array, which starts the index from 0 up to 2. Next, you will need to [implode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) it in some manner. Other answers are more explicit and use `foreach`, so this one provides an alternative, where you convert your array into the desired format via [array_map](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php). The `function` passed to `array_map` is a so-called callback, a `function` that is executed by `array_map` for each element, in this case, which is aware of the key and the value of each element. Now, we implode our input and, to make sure that we have some keys, we pass the result of [array_keys](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php).

```
$input = explode(",", "Hello,Howdy,Hola");
$output = implode('<br>', array_map(
    function ($v, $k) {
        return ($k + 1).'. '.$v;
    }, 
    $input, 
    array_keys($input)
));
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. You explained really well and made it easier for me to understand. However, I have a syntax error at $output implode which prompts unexpected identifier "implode"...I am unable to pass this code.. Any ideas?

Comment: @user6345655 thanks for pointing that out. It was a typo in my code indeed, apparently I did not push the ```=``` character between $output and implode hard-enough. Edited my answer.